# Cannot connect to a VPN server - authentication failed with error code 691

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, rras, nps

When trying to connect to a VPN server, I get the 691 error code on the client, which say:

> Error Description: 691: The remote
>   connection was denied because the user
>   name and password combination you
>   provided is not recognized, or the
>   selected authentication protocol is
>   not permitted on the remote access
>   server.

I validated that the username and password are correct. I also installed a certification to use with the `IKEv2` security type. I also validated that the VPN server support security method.

But I cannot login. In the server log I get this log:

> Network Policy Server denied access to
>   a user.
>
> The user DomainName\UserName connected
>   from IP address but failed an
>   authentication attempt due to the
>   following reason: The remote
>   connection was denied because the user
>   name and password combination you
>   provided is not recognized, or the
>   selected authentication protocol is
>   not permitted on the remote access
>   server.

Any idea of what can I do? 
Thanks in advance!

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          12/29/2010 7:12:20 AM
Event ID:      6273
Task Category: Network Policy Server
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Failure
User:          N/A
Computer:      VPN.domain.com
Description:
Network Policy Server denied access to a user.

Contact the Network Policy Server administrator for more information.

User:
  Security ID:          domain\Administrator
  Account Name:         domain\Administrator
  Account Domain:           domani
  Fully Qualified Account Name: domain.com/Users/Administrator

Client Machine:
  Security ID:          NULL SID
  Account Name:         -
  Fully Qualified Account Name: -
  OS-Version:           -
  Called Station Identifier:        192.168.147.171
  Calling Station Identifier:       192.168.147.191

NAS:
  NAS IPv4 Address:     -
  NAS IPv6 Address:     -
  NAS Identifier:           VPN
  NAS Port-Type:            Virtual
  NAS Port:         0

RADIUS Client:
  Client Friendly Name:     VPN
  Client IP Address:            -

Authentication Details:
  Connection Request Policy Name:   Microsoft Routing and Remote Access Service Policy
  Network Policy Name:      All
  Authentication Provider:      Windows
  Authentication Server:        VPN.domain.home
  Authentication Type:      EAP
  EAP Type:         Microsoft: Secured password (EAP-MSCHAP v2)
  Account Session Identifier:       313933
  Logging Results:          Accounting information was written to the local log file.
  Reason Code:          16
  Reason:               Authentication failed due to a user credentials mismatch. Either the user name provided does not map to an existing user account or the password was incorrect.
```

Answer (score 4):

> Reason:               Authentication
>   failed due to a user credentials
>   mismatch.  Either the user name provided does not map to an existing user account or the password was incorrect.

I think that's your problem right there.  Verify that the account has the correct permissions to connect remotely via RRAS.  These links might help you.  Note that articles that apply to 2003 may still apply to 2008r2 (according to MSFT).  Also note that I make no claim to being a subject matter expert....

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634(WS.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775658(WS.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759294(WS.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637783(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Administrator account should have remote access permissions. But thanks for you answer, I'll take a look in the links.

Comment: @stacker, you're right in that the admin account *should* have access, but I've had issues where I had to grant the administrator account explicit permissions to get regular RDP to work.  It might be something to look into.

Comment: right. I looked into it, and it has the permission. Both in the user setting on the Dial-In tab it has "allow access", and also in NPS network policy. I took it further in the network policy, and checked "accept users without validating credentials" but I got the same error. Errr... what should I look into next?

Comment: @stacker, I don't have anything off the top of my head, but I'll take some time later tonight to do some looking around.  Can't promise anything though...

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem so I'll go ahead and tell you what it was for me. My password (given to us by our host had a `$` in it). I was copy-pasting the password from an rdp shell script that had escaped the `$` with a `\`. I was mentally forgetting the reason for `\` and thinking it was literal. I spent hours working on authentication when in reality, I need only remove the back-slash escaping of the dollar sign.

Not sure if that's your problem -- but good luck.

Comment: Oh yeah, Stacker is asking before being sure that user-password were correct. That was the problem. I can't understand why he didn't mark your answer as correct. (Just being ironic BTW).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this my changing the Dial-In properties of the user. By default it was set to managed by NPS server. Click allow access solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As administrator, run **netsh ras set trace * enable**, then check C:\Windows\tracing\svchost_RASTLS.log

make sure you run **netsh ras set trace * disable** when you're done troubleshooting.

Also can check VPNIKE.log in that some folder.

Answer (score 0):

Been having same issue.  I am the admin and use my connection daily.  No changes anywhere.  I found a doc somewhere with a kinda similar issue and the solution was to disable IPv6 on the connection.  I did it and it worked.  It hasn't occurred again.

Comment: This helped me, too.